# Getting IAM permission error in EKS creation using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I am trying to create an IAM Policy for our EKS cluster creation. I need a policy that has minimal access for EKS cluster creation successfully. I created a policy and attached it with my IAM user and when I try to run it I am getting this error:

```
 Error: error reading EKS Add-On (drona-test-eks:coredns): AccessDeniedException: User is not authorized to perform this action
│ 
│   with aws_eks_addon.coredns,
│   on eks.tf line 126, in resource "aws_eks_addon" "coredns":
│  126: resource "aws_eks_addon" "coredns" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: error reading EKS Add-On (drona-test-eks:vpc-cni): AccessDeniedException: User is not authorized to perform this action
│ 
│   with module.eks.aws_eks_addon.this["vpc-cni"],
│   on .terraform/modules/eks/main.tf line 305, in resource "aws_eks_addon" "this":
│  305: resource "aws_eks_addon" "this" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: error reading EKS Add-On (drona-test-eks:kube-proxy): AccessDeniedException: User is not authorized to perform this action
│ 
│   with module.eks.aws_eks_addon.this["kube-proxy"],
│   on .terraform/modules/eks/main.tf line 305, in resource "aws_eks_addon" "this":
│  305: resource "aws_eks_addon" "this" {
```

I am not getting what I have to do to solve this issue. f anyone has any idea about it then please reply.

Thanks

Comment: You should post the policy.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is failing is the [vpc-cni](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managing-vpc-cni.html). This policy should solve that: `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy`

You can start with broad permissions to make your project work and then start restricting it to find what is strictly necessary.

Comment: It's throwing the same error.